# unexpected result after interpolating columns to target x-coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, interpolation

I am using `np.interp` to linearly interpolate two columns of data in a csv file to a list of target (expected) values. I converted the  target values to a numpy array. Each row in the csv file correspond to each value in the target data.

Here is a sample of data:

```
x= [246.72,   8.59, 194.4 , 145.73, 198.27]

v11         v12         
22.028949   22.863912   
0           9.006818    
134.238326  102.571956  
94.222921   107.823484  
200.163640  212.396264
```

script:

```
df['intrepo_v'] = pd.Series(dtype= 'float')
df['intrepo_v'] = np.interp(x, df['v11'].values,
df['v12'].values)
```

result:

```
42.579263
22.863912
42.579263
42.579263
42.579263
```

The aim of this interpolation is to create `intrepo_v` and move the values from `v11` and `v12` to some values close to `x`. Currently the result is not close to `v11`, `v12`, or `intrepo_v`. Can anyone suggest a way to solve this problem?

Comment: It is extremely unclear what you want to do. "How close" do you want them to be? `df['intrepo_v'] = x`?  Or `df['intrepo_v'] = 0.9*x + 0.1*df['v11']`? Anyway, the call to `np.interp(x_new, x_old, y_old)` would look where `x_new` lies relative to `x_old` and give the interpolated `y_old` value.  In your case that doesn't work, because `x_old` needs to be in increasing order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For numpy.interp the values must be increasing (see the help), scipy does not assume the values are sorted, try:

```
import scipy    
function=scipy.interpolate.interp1d(df['v11'].values,df['v12'].values)


df['intrepo_v'] =function(x)
```

or alternatively sort the input values with numpy